# Изменение значения чекбоксов в зависимости от значения другого чекбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно чтобы когда один чекбокс был в состоянии `checked`, три других были в таком же состоянии, как и первый.

```
var uhChbox = document.getElementById('uh-burger');
var otherChbox = $('.oth-check');
function btnsFun() {
    if (uhChbox.checked) {
        otherChbox.checked;
    }
    else {
        otherChbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При изменении состояния первого чекбокса нужно дублировать его состояние на остальные чекбоксы.
Для этого можно в обработчике события `change` для `#uh-burger` всем чекбоксам `.oth-check` проставлять в качестве значения свойства `checked` оное от `#uh-burger`:

```js
$("#uh-burger").on("change", function() {
  $(".oth-check").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="uh-burger" />
<input type="checkbox" class="oth-check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="oth-check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="oth-check" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А можно коварным и невалидным, но работающим способом: задать всем связанным чекбоксам один и тот же ID. Правда, при этом связывание будет двустороннее, но автор не упомянул, что это недопустимо  ;)